# Error in `ggsurvfit()`: ! `ggsurvfit()` cannot be used to plot objects of class <survfit2/survfitms/survfit>

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival, ggsurvfit

Can someone explain to me why this error message keeps coming up? My previous time-to-event analyses have all worked perfectly with the same commands.
Tank you.

My skript contains the following:

dfit <- survfit2(Surv(time, status) ~ intervention, data = Drugs_discon)

summary(dfit)

ggsurvfit(dfit)

Error in `ggsurvfit()`:
! `ggsurvfit()` cannot be used to plot objects of class <survfit2/survfitms/survfit>.
ℹ Use `ggcuminc()` for competing risks cumulative incidence plotting.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Questions do better here if they have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). In your case  that might start with posting the output of `dput(head(Drugs_discon))`. However, it looks like your object is of class `survfitms`, i.e. a multi-state model. Is it supposed to be? If so, you should plot a cumulative incidence curve as suggested. If not, you might want to sort out your `status` column - e.g. if it's a factor make sure it only has two levels.